# Parse login viewController not dismissing

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller, xcode7

I am working on an app using the parse login viewController but upon having the user login in the parse loginViewController is not dismissing. Any advice?
I do have the following code in the main viewcontroller

```
 func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Is `dismissViewControllerAnimated` being reached? Try adding a break point to make sure. Also, double check that you have set the `PFLogInViewController` as the delegate

Comment: I added the break point but it did not pause. Also I double checked that I had the PFLogInViewController as the delegate

Comment: If the breakpoint isn't being reached then the issue is with how the PFLogInViewController is being created and it's delegate methods. The function you have is called by the delgate when a user is logged in. Double check that you have followed the steps here https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views